# Integration of fluentd with Java application

Tags: spring, spring-boot, microservices, fluentd

I am working on integrating spring boot application with fluentd. 
When I use FluentdLogger in the application and source as forward in fluentd config file, I am able to log the entries to log file .

So How to provide log level to log statments in spring boot application, default is every statement is printed to file with tag.

Do I have to use in_tail with logging frameworks which will log to file and fluentd will tail from that file to another file.

OR there is way or appender in logback or logging frameworks in java.